# redux-form return action data invalid form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, redux-saga, redux-actions

1. When i valid my form, i've error 422 with data: error "invalid form".
2. However, my action get my data of my form
3. But don't send my data in my api after the call.
4. If anybody have one idea, i would like to understand better.
5. Thank you everyone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEDih.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXVqT.png)

**COMPONENT.JS**

```
 class CreatGroup extends React.Component{

 // function to post 

 handleFormSubmit = (dataForm) => {
 console.log(dataForm, ' DATA FORM')
 this.props.dispatch(createPostGroup(dataForm)) 
}

render() {
// my form
const { handleSubmit, submitting } = this.props
    return(
          <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit)}>
              <div>         
                <Field name="amount" component={renderField} type="number" label="amount" />
              </div>
              <div>
                <Field name="duration" component={renderField} type="number" label="duration" />
              </div>
              <div>
                <Field name="limit_members" component={renderField} type="number" label="max members" />
              </div>      
              <div>
                <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        )
       } 
      }

      CreatGroup = reduxForm({
       form:'creat-group'
      })(CreatGroup)
```

**ACTIONS.JS**

```
    // CONST ACTIONS 
    const CREATE_GROUP = 'CREATE_GROUP'

    //ACTIONS
     export function createPostGroup(data){ return { type: CREATE_GROUP, data}};
```

**REDUCER.JS**

```
    // REDUCER 
    export default function groupReducer( state= {}, action){
    switch (action.type){
    case CREATE_GROUP:
        return action.data
    case CREATE_GROUP_FAIL:
        return {
            ...state
        }
    default:
        return state
      }
     }
```

**COMBINE REDUCER.JS**

```
    // COMBINE REDUCER 
     const reducer = combineReducers({
      groupReducer,
      form: formReducer
     });
```

**SAGAS.JS**

Maybe the problem comes from there ?

```
   //  CALL API
    export function* createApiDataGroup(action){
     try { 
       const data = yield call(axios.post, 'http://localhost:8000/api/create');
       yield put({ type: "CREATE_GROUP", data })
     } catch (e) {
       yield put({ type: "CREATE_GROUP_FAIL", e})
     }
    } 

    export default function* mySaga() {
     yield all([
      takeEvery('CREATE_GROUP', createApiDataGroup)
     ])
    }
```

Comment: you need to export the component `export default reduxForm({
  form: 'createGroup' 
})(CreateGroup)` use this format. also make sure redux form is properly configured

Comment: thank you for you answer @Shivam, i've update my format but it's always same...